# When maximized, why is there a line break after the word "and"?

Tags: css

Thanks for reading.

**Rewritten to be more clear - sorry for all the confusion.**

Please use THIS jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ghr8L/5/

It's for this code:

```
<div style='overflow:hidden;background-color:black;'>

    <div style='overflow:hidden; color:white; float:left;'>
        <img style='width:64px; float:left; margin-right:10px;' src='https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2013/franz_kafkas_130th_birthday-1976005-hp.png' />
        Bookkeeping &amp; Business Services: Proven.  Reliable.  Accurate.<br>
        Hassle-Free bookkeeping with No B.S. - Give us a chance and we'll prove it.
    </div>

    <div style='float:right; margin-right: 10px; color:#EFDD6F; font-size:1.5em; line-height: 2em;'>(310) 204-4717</div>

</div>
```

**Everything is working exactly as needed, except for this one thing:**

1. Expand the window (or result pane) as big as you can make it.
2. **There is a line break after the word "and" even though there is a ton of space between the content and the phone number.**
3. Why?

I suspect it's something to do with the width of the image, since it works as expected if you take the image out, but I haven't found out what.

Thanks!

**Update: It is indeed the image with not counting toward the div width.**

While further researching this issue, I found this question: [A floated image does not count toward DIV width, how can I make it so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209660/a-floated-image-does-not-count-toward-div-width-how-can-i-make-it-so).  That doesn't exactly solve it, but does explain it.

I finally ended up going with something similar to AJP's suggestion.

The finall version is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ghr8L/18/

I really wish I could have the text wrap around the image as the width narrows, but screw it - I guess you can't have everything.  At least not in less than a million hours. =o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
<div style='overflow:hidden;background-color:black;'>


    <img style='width:64px; float:left; margin-right:10px;' src='https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2013/franz_kafkas_130th_birthday-1976005-hp.png' />
     <div style='overflow:hidden; color:white; float:left;'>
    Bookkeeping &amp; Business Services: Proven.  Reliable.  Accurate.<br>
        Hassle-Free bookkeeping with No B.S. - Give us a chance and we'll prove it.<br>
</div>

<div style='float:right; margin-right: 10px; color:#EFDD6F; font-size:1.5em; line-height: 2em;'>(310) 204-4717</div>
```

updated answer:

```
 <div style='overflow:hidden;background-color:black;'>

     <div style='overflow:hidden; color:white; float:left;'>
    <img style='width:64px; margin-right:10px;' src='https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2013/franz_kafkas_130th_birthday-1976005-hp.png' />
    Bookkeeping &amp; Business Services: Proven.  Reliable.  Accurate.<br>
        Hassle-Free bookkeeping with No B.S. - Give us a chance and we'll prove it.<br>
</div>

<div style='float:right; margin-right: 10px; color:#EFDD6F; font-size:1.5em; line-height: 2em;'>(310) 204-4717</div>

</div>
```

Comment: That definitely works.  Any idea why putting the image inside the div causes the line wrap?  Perhaps the image width is not used in the calculation for the div width?

Comment: Div works as block. so when img is put in with the text it tries to put them in block thats why you see line wrap. yes you may be write about image width is not used in the calculation. i am not sure about it so i can't speak. here is good reference page i found.. might have some info that is useful. [http://www.htmlquick.com/reference/tags/div.html] i am glad it solved your problem.

Comment: Can you think of a way to make the text wrap around the image, rather than the block falling below it?

Comment: i tried one more thing.. take out float:left from image.. it works for me

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems to solve: First, you have 
 tags that are setting the exact amount of text that will go on the line. You need to remove them.

But once you do that, the text will take up as much space as it can and push the phone number down below. The next thing you need to do is set a width on the div containing the image and the text. Try 60% and play with it from there.

A more complete, robust solution would be to use a grid system: http://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to remove the < br > from the text:

```
<div style='overflow:hidden;background-color:black;'>

    <div style='overflow:hidden; color:white; float:left;'>
        <img style='width:64px;margin-bottom:50px;float:left; margin-right:10px;' src='/img/bigGreenCheckmark.png' />
        Bookkeeping &amp; Business Services: Proven.  Reliable.  Accurate.
        Hassle-Free bookkeeping with No B.S. - Give us a chance and we'll prove it.
    </div>

    <div style='float:right; margin-right: 10px; color:#EFDD6F; font-size:1.5em; line-height: 2em;'>(310) 204-4717</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!  No difference though - check http://jsfiddle.net/Ghr8L/6/  Had to update for the image not showing up.  Still gets a linebreak after the word "and" in the second line.

Comment: add `margin-bottom:50px;` to the image `img` for it to magically be solved ;)

Answer (score 0):

why not width:100% in the parent div ?,

```
<div style='overflow:hidden; color:white; float:left;width:100%;'>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wx7ft/

or maybe i misunderstood your question ?

Comment: Hey, sorry there's some confusion with the jsFiddle.  Please use the updated one with the visible image.

Answer (score 0):

using `display: inline-block` and flexible widths is a possible solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ghr8L/13/

Comment: This is pretty good.  Can you think of a way to allow the text to expand after the number falls below?  It still only wants to fill 60%, event though it now doesn't have the number taking up space to the right of it.

Comment: change the widths to `max-width`? after the number falls below what? Not sure I understand what you're looking for